# Embed JS into template

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dowload and use this website menu bar from this free template:

https://jsfiddle.net/bootstrapious/ravpqxok

I just don't know how I get the Java script location embedded in, where would I put my JS file name that I've pasted the JS code from that website into the file for my website

```
assets/js/bar.min.js
```

```css
/*
*
* ==========================================
* CUSTOM UTIL CLASSES
* ==========================================
*
*/
.navbar {
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.navbar .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar .nav-link:hover,
.navbar .nav-link:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}


/* Change navbar styling on scroll */
.navbar.active {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar.active .nav-link {
    color: #555;
}

.navbar.active .nav-link:hover,
.navbar.active .nav-link:focus {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar.active .navbar-brand {
    color: #555;
}


/* Change navbar styling on small viewports */
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .navbar {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-brand, .navbar .nav-link {
        color: #555;
    }
}



/*
*
* ==========================================
* FOR DEMO PURPOSES
* ==========================================
*
*/
.text-small {
    font-size: 0.9rem !important;
}


body {
    min-height: 110vh;
    background-color: #4ca1af;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #4ca1af 0%, #c4e0e5 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <!-- Navbar-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script>
        $(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
    </script>
<header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top py-3">
        <div class="container"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Transparent Nav</a>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            
            <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>


<!-- For demo purpose -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="pt-5 text-white">
        <header class="py-5 mt-5">
            <h1 class="display-4">Transparent Navbar</h1>
            <p class="lead mb-0">Using Bootstrap 4 and Javascript, create a transparent navbar which changes its style on scroll.</p>
            <p class="lead mb-0">Snippet by
                <a href="https://bootstrapious.com" class="text-white">
                    <u>Bootstrapious</u></a>
            </p>
        </header>
        <div class="py-5">
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong class="font-weight-bold">consectetur adipisicing </strong>elit. Explicabo consectetur odio voluptatum facere animi temporibus, distinctio tempore enim corporis quam <strong class="font-weight-bold">recusandae </strong>placeat! Voluptatum voluptate, ex modi illum quas nam distinctio.</p>
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <div class="py-5">
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong class="font-weight-bold">consectetur adipisicing </strong>elit. Explicabo consectetur odio voluptatum facere animi temporibus, distinctio tempore enim corporis quam <strong class="font-weight-bold">recusandae </strong>placeat! Voluptatum voluptate, ex modi illum quas nam distinctio.</p>
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididkkkkokokokokokorkgokrgokrgokrgokrgokrogkrogkorgkunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididkkkkokokokokokorkgokrgokrgokrgokrgokrogkrogkorgkunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</head>
</html>
```

I have got all the code from JSfiddle into my website, just the html/css page isn't locating the JS file.

Comment: To just make it work , you can simply paste the js code under script tag in your html page.

Comment: Please share your code for better debugging. As @saravana said you can put js part in a script tag.But be aware that for making the template work you have add Resources (jquery,bootstrap,...) in the head tag of your html.

Comment: I added tihe first post my code. Thanks for the responses so far. It helped get the bar to load in, now it's just not making the bar transparent and then not transparent as you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **jQuery** as a dependency. Without it, your js code won't work. Inside the `<head>` tag, put this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and after that, you can place your js code. You also should put your HTML code inside the tag `<body>`, not inside `<head>`.